# Can the bottom stair have a different height than the rest in GA?

Tags: code-compliance, stairs

Have spiral staircase in which all the riders but the bottom one are the same height. Is that acceptable in GA?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing that if this happens to be OK, it will depend on how much the difference is. It would probably be good if you could include the measurements for the height of the bottom vs the other risers.

Comment: It will be a stumbling hazard for anyone not accustomed to it. While on a trip in Russia we found most stairs were like this ( out side of Moscow), I guess a lack of standardization. We learned to look at all stairs for non-standard height at the top or bottom step to avoid falling.

Comment: Is the bottom step taller or shorter than the others? Taller would be more of a problem than shorter.

Comment: I think it is nationwide, the difference can only be 3/8" from the shortest riser to the tallest. That means you can have risers that are 7" and 7 3/8" in a set of steps, but you can't go to 7 3/4" thinking it is only 3/8" difference than the one next to it. I does not matter if it is the last one or the first one, or any in between.

Answer (score 11):

The maximum rise of steps is 8”. The maximum difference between risers is 3/8” from smallest to largest, as @Jack says. (See ICC R311.5.3.1)

A handrail is required if there are 4 or more risers.

Exterior steps have some exceptions.